# Python - read 2d array from binary data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary, endianness

I try to read a 2d array with floats from a binary file with Python. Files have been written with big endian by a Fortran program (it is the intermediate file of the Weather Research and Forecast model). I already know dimension sizes of the array to read (nx & ny) but as a Fortran and IDl programer I am completely lost, how to manage it in Python. (Later on I want to visualize the array).

1. Shall I use `struct.unpack` or `numpy.fromfile` or the `array module`?
2. Do I have to read first a vector and afterwards reshape it? (have seen this option only for the numpy-way)
3. How do I define a 2d array with numpy and how do I define the dtype to read with big-endian byte ordering?
4. Is there an issue with array ordering (column or row wise) to take into account?

Comment: Do you know if Fortran saves some meta-information (i.e. the dimension) along with the values? Or is this just a constant "stream" of `nx*ny` big-endian numbers?

Comment: You could try `scipy.io.FortranFile` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.FortranFile.html).  Note the comments in the docstring; whether or not `FortranFile` will work depends on the Fortran compiler.

Comment: Doesn't WRF create files in NetCDF format?  (Perhaps being an "intermediate file" is the issue.)

Comment: In the Fortran file there are various meta-information before the data field. I could read this information and so know the dimensions nx and ny. But I am still not able to read the array due to the problems mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, WRF works with Grib files as input and NetCDF files as output. But there are also files with a WRF specific binary format, which are a kind of gate when using NetCDF files as input.

Answer (score 2):

Short answers per sub-question:

1. I don't think the `array` module has a way to specify endianness.
   Between the `struct` module and Numpy I think Numpy is easier to
   use, especially for Fortran-like ordered arrays.
2. All data is inherently 1-dimensional as far as the hardware (disk,
   RAM, etc) is concerned, so yes reshaping to get a 2D representation
   is always necessary. With `numpy.fromfile` the reshape must happen
   explicitly afterwards, but `numpy.memmap` provides a way to reshape
   more implicitly.
3. The easiest way to specify endianness with Numpy is to use a short
   [type string](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types), actually very similar to the [approach needed for
   the `struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment). In Numpy `>f` and `>f4` specify single
   precision and `>d` and `>f8` double precision big-endian floating
   point.
4. Your binary file could walk the array along the rows (C-like) or along 
   the columns (Fortran-like). Whichever of the two, this has to be taken into
   account to represent the data properly. Numpy makes this easy with the
   `order` keyword argument for `reshape` and `memmap` (among others).

All in all, the code could be for example:

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'somethingsomething'

with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    nx, ny = ...  # parse; advance file-pointer to data segment
    data = np.fromfile(f, dtype='>f8', count=nx*ny)
    array = np.reshape(data, [nx, ny], order='F')
```

Comment: Many thanks, moarningsun ! Your explanations helped me to solve the problem !